# Error in Xml Creation from as per Database tables : .Net Core 3.1 Memory Leak

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-3.1

I am setting up a Method for getting the Xml data,whose data are getting from Database tables. The above functionality was working till the `.Net Core2.1` project updated to `.Net Core 3.1.1`.
This below code shows the error.

**Template.cs**

```
 orderTemplate =
                  (from ordt in _context.OrderTemplates
                   where ordt.Id == orderTempId // int orderTempId=1;
                   select new XElement("OrderTemplate",
                          new XElement("OrderTemplateId", ordt.Id),
                          new XElement("OrderTemplateName", ordt.Name),
                          new XElement("OrderTemplateDescription", ordt.Description)));
```

**Exception**

```
Client projection contains reference to constant expression of 'System.Xml.Linq.XName'. 
This could potentially cause memory leak. Consider assigning this constant to local variable 
and using the variable in the query instead. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2103067 for more information.
```

**XML Data format:(Expected Output)**

```
<OrderTemplate>
  <OrderTemplateId>1</OrderTemplateId>
  <OrderTemplateName>BBCSeat</OrderTemplateName>
  <OrderTemplateDescription>Boeing Business Class Seat</OrderTemplateDescription>
</OrderTemplate>
```

**Template.cs(Rediited)**

```
 orderTemplate =
                  (from ordt in _context.OrderTemplates
                   where ordt.Id == orderTemplateId
                  select new {
                  _OrderTemplate = ordt,
                 _OperationTemplates =(from ot in _context.OrderTemplates                                                
                                       join opt in _context.OperationTemplates 
                                     on ot.Id equals opt.OrderTemplateId into ps1                                               
                                    from opt in ps1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    join asm in _context.AssemblyUnits
                                    on opt.AssemblyUnitId equals asm.Id into ps5
                                   from asm in ps5.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                    where ot.Id == ordt.Id
                                      orderby opt.OrderBy ascending
                                      select new
                                                {
                                                    _OperationTemplate =  opt,
                                                    _Assembly =  asm,
})}).AsEnumerable();
```

Already know this is repeated question, but what wrong coding I am doing here. Kindly guide me.

Comment: You may want to read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes

Comment: @jdweng already went through..this may be the error: LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client and checked this https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12795 too. Dont know its right or wrong?

Comment: I agree it is the root cause but not necessarily the actual cause.  I think the model may need to be refreshed.  The error seems to imply that the orderTempId should be a parameter : where ordt.Id == orderTempId.  So if the query is now a stored procedure (run on server not client) the variable should be a parameter.

Comment: The impletation like this ordetTempId coming from Api  , passes through tables OrderTemp, based upon the id's of this table, Actions table are taken and so on..

Comment: Is API compatible with Core 3.0+?

Comment: No it was compatible with 2.1.1

Comment: So do you need a new API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the entities before projecting them into XML.  That's what EF Core 2.1 did anyway.

```
 var orderTemplates =_context.OrderTemplates.Where(ordt=> ordt.Id == orderTempId).AsEnumerable();

 var orderTemplate =
                  (from ordt in orderTemplates 
                   select new XElement("OrderTemplate",
                          new XElement("OrderTemplateId", ordt.Id),
                          new XElement("OrderTemplateName", ordt.Name),
                          new XElement("OrderTemplateDescription", ordt.Description))).ToList();
```

Conceptually first line of code builds the query, translates it to SQL, runs the SQL query and returns an IEnumerable that can consume the results.

The second line enumerates the query results as `orderTemplate` objects and projects them into the XElements and copies them to a List.

Comment: what if there n level?

Comment: It's exactly the same logic.  You just put `AsEnumerable()` after the `where` to control the boundary between server-side and client-side evaluation.

Comment: Thanks @David Browne - Microsoft , Would you mind to explain or give any support link ?